How to use AOS and loadash in the nuxt3.12؟؟
I installed two packages "Nuxt-aos" and "lodash" with pnpm libraries into my project and after that, I added these two to my nuxt.config.ts:
modules: [
 "nuxt-aos",
 "nuxt-lodash"
],

after I write a data-aos as an attribute in one of my tags (e.g.  div tag) I get this error message in the console:
"SyntaxError: The requested module/_nuxt/node_modules/.pnpm/lodash.debounce@4.0.8/node_modules/lodash.debounce/index.js?v=443b1030' does not provide an export named 'default"
I tried to write a separate plugin but it's not working any idea how can I solve this issue?

Seems to be a known bug of nuxt-aos in combination with pnpm. Here you can find the issue: https://github.com/egidiusmengelberg/nuxt-aos/issues/25
